# Deleting already duplicated Filestream Files

Tags: sql-server-2012, filestream

I have three FileStreams (`FS1 on F drive, FS2 on H drive, FS3 on E drive`) belonging to the same FileStream group of one particular database (DB) which is in Simple recovery mode in the SQL Server 2012.

FS1 contains huge number of files due to which F drive is completely full.

So, I am trying to move some of the extra files from one FileStream (FS1 on F drive) to another FileStreams (FS2 on H drive and FS3 on E drive) using command:

```
dbcc shrinkfile('FS1', emptyfile)
```

Then, I take the Full and Differential backup of the database and issue the CheckPoint and try to delete the already duplicated files from the Filestream FS1 to get some space in the F drive using command:

```
sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection @dbname = 'DB' , @filename = 'FS1
```

But still no files get deleted and I receive the output as such:

> file_name num_collected_items num_marked_for_collection_items num_unprocessed_items last_collected_lsn
>
> DB_FS1 0 0 0 25000001749500000

Please suggest how to delete these already duplicated files.